# Get all request names and codes from Network when navigating to a page

Tags: java, http-headers

is there a way to get all header requests that are visible on the page when opening the Network tab in a browser programmatically? For instance, when opening the Network tab when navigating to Google, I see 24 requests. Is it possible to get all their names and status codes using some sort of Java class? Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

http://s32.postimg.org/wkym0oqtx/request_url_and_status_code_1.jpg

Thank you.